# Three persons at queue.

Tags: probability

I've got following problem.

N people $n \ge 3$ stand in queue. Amongst them are persons X,Y,Z. Calculate probability of an event : X stands before Y (not necessarily directly), if its known that Z stand right after Y.

So, do I think right?

A - X before Y

B - Y before Z

$\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)!}{n!}$ because YZ can be set starting from 1st place and $n-2$ people on each other

But let's think :

If I set X to 1st place, then I can set YZ to $n-2$ places

If I set X to 2nd place, then I can set YZ to $n-3$ places

So maybe it is total probability and

$|A \cap B| = 1 \cdot (n-2)\cdot(n-3)!+1\cdot(n-3)\cdot(n-3)! + 1\cdot(n-4)\cdot(n-3)! + ...+ 1*\cdot(n-(n-1))\cdot(n-3)! = (n-3)!(n^2+(2+3+....+n-1))=(n-3)!(n^2+(1+2+...+n)-1-n)=(n-3)!(n^2+\frac{n^2+1}{2}-1-n)=\frac{1}{2}(n-3)!(n-2)(n-1)$

$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)= \frac{0.5(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{2n}$

Hereby,

$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{1}{2n} \cdot n = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: That's the long way, but way more painful than you have to. Putting $Z$ after $Y$ just means you are permuting $n-1$ people - the people excepting $Z$, then putting $Z$ after. And putting $Z$ after, doesn't affect whether $X$ comes before or after $Y$, so we can just forget about $Z$. Now notice by symmetry that $X$ has to come before $Y$ just as often as $Y$ comes before $X$.

Comment: Thats clever. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can fix $YZ$ and treat them as one as they always seem to be together anyways (e.g. there is no randomness in $Z$ to account for if we know $Y$). If then there is a uniform distribution to where $YZ$ stand. Then the probability space for X standing in front of $YZ$ ("above" in the table) would be a triangle like in the table below

$$\frac{1}{6 \cdot 5}\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bf 0&1&1&1&1\\
\bf 0&\bf 0&1&1&1\\
0&\bf 0&\bf 0&1&1\\
0&0&\bf 0&\bf 0&1\\
0&0&0&\bf 0&\bf 0\\
0&0&0&0&\bf 0
\end{array}\right]$$Example uniform probability space if 6 people. The bold-fat positions are for $YZ$. Here it is $4+3+2+1 = 10$ out of $30$ positions. In general it would be $(n-2)(n-1)/2$ out of $(n-1)n$ positions. So half is not too far off, but the whole space just gets displaced one step upwards as two people take double space compared to as one would.